# Is there any way to symbolize a user-supplied input parameter in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have a model built in ESRI ModelBuilder that is run from its tool dialog, where the user supplies the input feature layer that then gets processed in the model.  I need the input feature layer to get a certain symbology when the model is run.  I've tried symbolizing it by right-clicking the input layer in ModelBuilder, going to its Properties, and setting the layer symbology using a layer file. I then save & run the model, and the input feature layer is still not symbolized - it just stays the same.

Am I doing it wrong?

I can get output layers in the model to symbolize using layer files just fine with no issues.

Is there no way to symbolize inputs... only outputs?

I'm also open to using Python to symbolize it, but not sure if this is possible?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using? Is it on the ArcMap Data View during an interactive session that you are wanting to see this symbolization occur?